# $C^1$ function on the ball hits $0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question is two parts. Suppose $B$ denotes the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ is an open set containing the ball. Let $f$ be a $C^1$, rank $n$ function $U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||f(x) - x|| < 1/2$ for $x \in U$. First, show that $||f||^2$ attains a minimum in the interior of $B$. Second, show that $f$ actually hits $0$.

It is not so hard to see that the second claim implies the first. This is because $||f||^2$ cannot possibly be any smaller than $0$, so if $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$, this is as low as it goes. It is a minimum since $f$ is rank $n$, and thus a local homeomorphism by the inverse function theorem. This implies it is locally injective, and thus a local minimum. It must happen in the ball, since the inequality given says in fact it has to happen in the open ball of radius $1/2$.

It is a common theme among the writers of these questions that the first part be a special case of the second, which is often times provable without the first. Thus I'd like to find an argument which establishes this fact directly.

Any hints?

Comment: $\|f\|^2$ is a continuous function on $U$ and therefore takes on a minimum on the compact subset $B$. I don't follow what you're saying: $f$ is locally injective, but what does that tell you about $\|f\|$?

Comment: The only way $||f(x)||^2 = 0$ is if $f(x) = 0$. This can only happen once in a neighborhood of any particular point, so it is a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ denote the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^n.$ The condition on $Df(x)$ implies $f(B)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n,$ by the inverse function theorem. The result we're after thus follows from a stronger result: Assume $f: \overline B \to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous, and $f(B)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$. If $|f(x)-x| \le 1/2$ for $x\in \overline B,$ then $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in B.$

Proof: First, an exercise that I'll let you verify: If $V\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open and $V$ contains a point $x_0$ of minimal norm, then $x_0=0.$

To prove the result, first observe $|f(0)| \le 1/2.$ Because $f(B)$ is open, there is an open ball centered at $f(0)$ that is contained in $f(B).$ Hence $f(B)$ contains points whose norm is $<1/2.$

Next observe that the triangle inequality implies that if $|x|=1,$ then $|f(x)| \ge 1/2.$  Thus the minimum value of $|f|$ on $\overline B,$ which exists because $\overline B$ is compact, must occur in $B.$ Therefore $f(B)$ contains an element of minimal norm. By the exercise, $0\in f(B)$ and we're done.

Comment: So minima of the norm appear only when it's derivative is singular, but $f$ is rank $n$, so it only happens when the function $x \mapsto \sum x_i^2$ is singular, which happens when $f$ takes on the value $0$. Sound right?

Comment: @AlfredYerger  I'm thinking this way: Let $V$ be the open unit ball. We know $f(V)$ is open and contains an element of minimal norm. But no open set contains an element of minimal norm unless that element is $0.$

Comment: @AlfredYerger I edited to a more complete answer.

Comment: Edited yet again. I noticed that $<1/2$ could be replaced by $\le 1/2.$